# Resource stringtable is overwritten when including midaslib

Tags: delphi, resources, delphi-10.2-tokyo, resourcestring

When I include `midaslib` in my uses clause, the resource stringtable is overriden with '0: succesfull completion' and 15 empty strings.

I include a precompiled .Res file.

Original Test program :

```
program tesresources;

{$R BKHTEKSTEN.RES}

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  main in 'main.pas' {Form1};

  {$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
//Form1
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:Integer;
  astr:string;
begin
  MEMOtest.BeginUpdate;
  try
    MEMOtest.Lines.Clear;    
    MEMOTest.Lines.Add('Resourstrings : ');    
    for i := 0 to 255 do begin
      astr:=LoadStr(i);
      MEMOTest.Lines.Add(i.ToString+' : '+aStr);
    end;
  finally
    MEMOtest.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Result :

> Resourstrings :  0 :  1 : Pingwin 5 - Fout! 2 : Ok! 3 : Pingwin 5 -
>   Bericht ! 4 : Kan bestand niet openen ! 5 : Weet u het zeker ? 6 :
>   Verwijderen! 7 :  8 :  9 : Opgelet : Deze informatie gaat definitief
>   verloren !!! 10 :  11 : Opgelet : Het geselecteerde Boekjaar zal
>   volledig verwijderd worden !!! 12 : Opgelet : De BTW Listing zal
>   definitief verwijderd worden !!! 13 : Opgelet : Verwijderen van de
>   Ouderdomshistorieken !!! 14 : Opgelet : Verwijderen van de Historieken
>   klanten/Leveranciers !!! 15 : Opgelet : Deze Klant zal Definitief
>   verwijderd worden !!! 16 : Opgelet : Deze Leverancier zal Definitief
>   Verwijderd worden !!! 17 : Opgelet : Deze Contactinformatie zal
>   Definitief verwijderd worden !!!

When inluding Midaslib, the resource stringtable is changed.

```
program tesresources;

{$R BKHTEKSTEN.RES}

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  midaslib,
  main in 'main.pas' {Form1};

  {$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

> Resourstrings :  **0 : Successful completion.** 1 :  2 :  3 :  4 :  5 :  6
>   :  7 :  8 :  9 :  10 :  11 :  12 :  13 :  14 :  15 :  16 : Opgelet :
>   Deze Leverancier zal Definitief Verwijderd worden !!! 17 : Opgelet :
>   Deze Contactinformatie zal Definitief verwijderd worden !!!

When looking in the .exe I find two stringtables
[image: Original stringtable]
[image: New stringtable]

Comment: If you can, use FireDAC and forget `TClientDataSet`.

Comment: The problem arises in a big application and we cannot migrate all clientdatasets to firedac, so we need a solution in the meantime.

Comment: Move your stringtable to a different index than 1. Clearly MidasLib contains a stringtable 1 resource that is overwriting yours, and it's highly unlikely that EMBT is going to move theirs.